# Insert and update CSV file data into MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am inserting record from CSV file to MySQL table if any record already exists update that record and insert other records and if there is no match of the record insert all records.

Here is my code

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

$cid = mysql_select_db('test', $connect);


define('CSV_PATH', '/home/ubc/Documents/');

$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "test.csv";
$csvfile  = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData  = fgets($csvfile);

$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile)) {

    $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
    $csv_array  = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
    $insert_csv = array();

    $insert_csv['name']  = $csv_array[0];
    $insert_csv['email'] = $csv_array[1];

    $query = mysql_query("select * from test");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($count == 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO test(name,email)VALUES('" . $insert_csv['name'] . "','" . $insert_csv['email'] . "')";

        $n = mysql_query($query, $connect);
        $i++;
    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("select name from test where name='" . $insert_csv['name'] . "'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            if ($count) {
                $sql = "update test set email='" . $insert_csv['email'] . "'";
                $qu  = mysql_query($sql);

            } else {

                $query = "INSERT INTO test(name,email)VALUES('" . $insert_csv['name'] . "','" . $insert_csv['email'] . "')";

                $n = mysql_query($query, $connect);

                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

fclose($csvfile);

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: remove duplicates from your csv file.. Then start inserting records.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php

        $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
        if (!$connect) {
            die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $cid = mysql_select_db('test', $connect);


        define('CSV_PATH', '/home/ubc/Documents/');

        $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "test.csv";
        $csvfile  = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
        $theData  = fgets($csvfile);

        $i = 0;
        while (!feof($csvfile)) {

            $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
            $csv_array  = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
            $insert_csv = array();

            $insert_csv['name']  = $csv_array[0];
            $insert_csv['email'] = $csv_array[1];

            $query = mysql_query("select name from test where name='" . $insert_csv['name'] . "'");
            $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if ($count == 0) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO test(name,email)VALUES('" . $insert_csv['name'] . "','" . $insert_csv['email'] . "')";

                $n = mysql_query($query, $connect);

            } else {
                $sql = "update test set email='" . $insert_csv['email'] . "'";
                        $qu  = mysql_query($sql);
            }
 $i++;
            }
        }

        fclose($csvfile);

        echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
        mysql_close($connect);
        ?>
```

Comment: check record is unique or not using name field. If yes than insert otherwise update.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer its inserting records and also update, but while update the records its makes all updated fields blank.

Comment: $sql = "update test set email='" . $insert_csv['email'] . "'";
 Replace above query with this
  $sql = "update test set email='" . $insert_csv['email'] . "'" where name='" . $insert_csv['name'] . "'");

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow query..

```
INSERT INTO table (primkey, col2, col3) VALUES(1, 2, 3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
col1=VALUES(1), col2=VALUES(2)
```

Its example.

This may help you

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: I have tried this its just inserting records not updating